# Beautiful Soup AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to run a Beautiful Soup script that scraps a menu. It first gets a list of food items, then in a for loop goes up the tree to find which meal the food is served during, and which dining hall the food is served at. It then adds the information to a dictionary with the food being the key and the meal and dining hall being the value. Here's the code:

```
foodDict = {}
foodList = bsObj.findAll("td")
for foodItem in foodList:
    print("foodItems: " +foodItem.getText())
    meal = foodItem.parent.parent.parent.find("h4").getText().lower()
    print("Meal: " +meal)
    diningHall = foodItem.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.find("h2").getText().lower()
    s = "-"
    seq = (meal, diningHall)
    mealAndHall = s.join(seq)
    foodDict[foodItem.getText().lower().strip()] = mealAndHall
    print(foodDict)
```

It goes through the first run of the loop, but when it goes for the second, it returns an error:

```
foodItems: Bacon
Meal: breakfast
{'bacon': 'breakfast-chase/duckett'}
foodItems: Hard & Soft Cooked Eggs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "menuscrape.py", line 24, in <module>
    meal = foodItem.parent.parent.parent.find("h4").getText().lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Can someone just explain why I'm getting the error? Is the object that is NoneType a foodItem? Why would my code get the information I need on the first run, but not on subsequent runs? I don't completely understand. Also, it would be nice if anyone has any tips on how to change the repeated parents.parents.parents.parents... I'm still learning, so if you'd rather withhold the information that's fine. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Here's the source:

```
url = "https://www.smith.edu/diningservices/menu_poc/cbord_menus.php"
response = requests.get(url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```

Output wanted:

```
{'bacon': 'breakfast-chase/duckett', 'hard & soft cooked eggs': 'breakfast-chase/duckett', 'fried eggs': 'breakfast-chase/duckett', 'morning glory muffins': 'breakfast-chase/duckett', 'rolled oats': 'breakfast-chase/duckett', 'red grapes': 'breakfast-chase/duckett', 'red grapes': 'breakfast-chase/duckett', 'fresh pineapple': 'breakfast-chase/duckett', 'crudites & dip': 'lunch-chase/duckett', 'vegan pesto pizza': 'lunch-chase-duckett', 'pepperoni pizza': 'lunch-chase/duckett', 'extra cheese pizza': 'lunch-chase/duckett', 'caesar salad': 'lunch-chase/duckett', 'chocolate chip bars': 'lunch-chase/duckett', 'assorted fruit': 'dinner-chase/duckett', 'london broil': 'dinner-chase/duckett', 'vegan mushroom tofu': 'dinner-chase/duckett', 'oven-browned red potatoes': 'dinner-chase/duckett', 'baby carrots w/ parsley': 'dinner-chase/duckett', 'hummingbird cake w/ frosting': 'dinner-chase/duckett'}
```

Comment: post the output you want

Comment: I've updated the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
foodDict = {}
Chase = soup.select_one('.context')
h2 = Chase.h2.text.lower()
for div in Chase.select('.col-xs-4'):
    h4 = div.h4.text.lower()
    value = '-'.join((h4,h2))

    for food in div('td'):
        key = food.text.strip().lower()
        foodDict[key] = value
```

out:

```
{'assorted fruit': 'dinner-chase/duckett',
 'baby carrots w/ parsley': 'dinner-chase/duckett',
 'bacon': 'breakfast-chase/duckett',
 'caesar salad': 'lunch-chase/duckett',
 'chocolate chip bars': 'lunch-chase/duckett',
 'crudites & dip': 'lunch-chase/duckett',
 'extra cheese pizza': 'lunch-chase/duckett',
 'fresh pineapple': 'breakfast-chase/duckett',
 'fried eggs': 'breakfast-chase/duckett',
 'hard & soft cooked eggs': 'breakfast-chase/duckett',
 'hummingbird cake w/ frosting': 'dinner-chase/duckett',
 'london broil': 'dinner-chase/duckett',
 'morning glory muffins': 'breakfast-chase/duckett',
 'oven-browned red potatoes': 'dinner-chase/duckett',
 'pepperoni pizza': 'lunch-chase/duckett',
 'red grapes': 'breakfast-chase/duckett',
 'rolled oats': 'breakfast-chase/duckett',
 'vegan mushroom tofu': 'dinner-chase/duckett',
 'vegan pesto pizza': 'lunch-chase/duckett'}
```